# test file existence from a symlink path

Tags: bash

I have the following script:

```
if [ -e "/home/$USER/works/bash/mv-to-parent.sh" ] ; then
    # do something...
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

executing it I get every time the "not found" message even if the file it's there; I've understood the problem is related to the fact that the "works" folder is a symlink ( /home/$USER/works -> /media/data/works).

Is it possible to make it work using the symlink path?

Answer (score 0):

If you think the symlink is the issue, then use `readlink -f`, e.g.:

```
if [ -e "$(readlink -f "/home/$USER/works/bash/mv-to-parent.sh")" ] ; then
    # do something...
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

However, I am not sure it will fix your issue. Except `-h` and `-L`, [all file-based tests should already dereference symbolic links](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test).

Comment: unfortunally this doesn't work; I'm sure it's related to the fact that works folder is a symlink, in fact if I test `if [ -e "/media/data/works/mv-to-parent.sh" ]` it works as expected; it seems that it doesn't work properly if the path you are testing contains a symlink in it

Comment: Try typing `readlink -f "/home/$USER/works/bash/mv-to-parent.sh"` to your console, because if it shows the folder you want then what I suggested is exactly equivalent to hardcoding the destination of the symlink. Otherwise simply `echo "/home/$USER/works/bash/mv-to-parent.sh"` from *within* your script. It will show you if, e.g. `$USER` is not defined or defined somewhere else.

Comment: well if type `readlink ...` the result is the folder it is supposed to be, as  you said; but once used in the script, it fails; I can't say exactly why that happens...

Comment: @CerealKiller and what does `echo "/home/$USER/works/bash/mv-to-parent.sh"` output when called from *within* the script?

Comment: I think you got it, since it outputs `/home/root/works/bash/mv-to-parent.sh`... I'm launching the script with sudo, but wasn't expected $USER to be "root"